# Azure Blob Name includes Subfolder when outputting Name

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a container in Azure and within this container I have a subfolder.

The problem is that when I get the blob Name, rather than just having `test.doc`, the name is showing `subfolder/test.doc`

Is there a way that I only get the Filename showing rather than the subfolder and filename?

For example:

```
systemdesign/templates/test.docx
```

With `systemdesign` being the `container`, `templates` the subfolder and `test.docx` the document.

I want to show only: `test.docx`

Is there anyway? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Azure Blob storage has no folder structure to speak of - you only can fake it as you are by including the full path as part of the blob name.

What you can do is the following:

`var name  = blob.Name.Substring(blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/'));`

So name should equal "test.doc" after running that code.

Comment: Close actually, had to add `+1` after as that code showed me `/test.doc` meaning `var name  = blob.Name.Substring(blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/') +1);` but otherwise worked like a charm :)

Comment: Good to hear - Thanks